# How to insert div inside another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

I need to insert the div inside the dive before all other its contents,  the problem is I don't have div ids, I only have classes as selector. Div generation is not in my control.

Suppose,

```
<div class="divClass" >
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
</div>
<div class="divClass">
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
</div>
```

And I need to insert the dynamic `div` inside the outer div with class 'divClass'. So output would look like this,

```
<div class="divClass" >
    <div id="mydiv" class="mydivclass"></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
</div>
<div class="divClass">
    <div id="mydiv" class="mydivclass"></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
    <div class="divInnerClass" ></div>
</div>
```

I have tried as below,

```
function AddSubMenuHeadings() {
            //Get all grouping for each menu 
            //1.Files Menu
            $('.filesMenu .divClass').each(function (index, ele) {
                debugger;
                var e = $('<div style="display:block; float:left;">somesubmenuheading</div>');
                var element = $('.filesMenu .' + ele.className + ' .divInnerClass')[0];
                $(element).before(e);
                e.attr('id', 'myid');
                //alert(ele);
            });
        }
```

but this is giving me wrong output. It is inserting the all dynamically generated divs inside first parent div.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Yes, It just example code mistake. I am handling the id part of it.

Comment: `$(ele).prepend(e);` instead of `$(element).before(e);` -- the var `ele` in the loop refers to the `.divClass` element you want to add the item to.

Comment: @Ted Thanks man. Now I am feeling stupid. Write as an answer I will mark it as answer.

Comment: @user2745246 Added it below, with tweaks for jQueryness :)

Comment: append() & prepend() are for inserting content inside an element (making the content its child) while after() & before() insert content outside an element (making the content its sibling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `$(ele).prepend(e);` instead of `$(element).before(e);`-- in your example, the var `ele` in the loop refers to the `.divClass` element you want to add the item to.

However, I would write it a little differently, like this:

```
$('.filesMenu .divClass').each(function (index, ele) {
    var $div = $('<div/>')
        .css({'display':'block', 'float':'left'})
        .attr('id', 'myId')//make the id dynamic
        .prependTo(ele);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the prepend function of jQuery.
Here is working fiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".divClass").prepend('<div id="mydiv" class="mydivclass">NEW CONTENT</div> ');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divClass">
    <div class="divInnerClass">asdg</div>
    <div class="divInnerClass">asdg</div>
    <div class="divInnerClass">asdg</div>
    <div class="divInnerClass">asdg</div>
</div>
<div class="divClass">
    <div class="divInnerClass">asdg</div>
    <div class="divInnerClass">asdg</div>
    <div class="divInnerClass">asdg</div>
    <div class="divInnerClass">asdg</div>
</div>
<button>Prepend div</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use **jQuery `.prepend()`** ?

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 1):

```
function AddSubMenuHeadings() {
        $('.filesMenu .divClass').each(function (index, ele) {
            var e = $('<div style="display:block; float:left;">somesubmenuheading</div>');

            $(ele).prepend(e);
            e.attr('id', 'myid');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 $(element).before(e);
```

For:

```
$(element).prepend(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're going to be assigning IDs to dynamically created DOM elements, the IDs must be unique. This is pretty trivial.

If you're using jQuery, why not use a `prepend()`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divClass").prepend(e);
});
```